# Guessing a number using if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

Well I'm trying to guess series of numbers closest to the winning number (ignoring the possibility of a tie) let just say the winning number is 15.

I also want to make sure it doesnt exceed the winning number. One last condition is that there will be no winners if all the guesses are too big.

Suppose the number are as follows:

```
12
9 
7
13
4
0
```

I want the program to choose 13 as the winning number.

this is a snipped of the code i wrote:

```
corrrectGuess = 15
while(contestantGuess != 0) {
    if(contestantGuess <= correctGuess) {
        winningGuess = contestantGuess;
    }
}
```

but that will make all the numbers to be the winning guess.

Can someone help me construct a proper if statement or writing only the pseudo-code will also be helpful.

Comment: Try `if(contestantGuess <= correctGuess && winningGuess <= contestantGuess)`

Comment: Please note your actual code will result in an infinite loop as your while condition will never be false as you don't change `correctGuess` value inside the loop.

Comment: Is your program supposed to make the guesses itself, or is it given the guesses as an input and is supposed to pick the best guess? Different parts of your question seem to imply different things.

Comment: sorry guys there was a mistake in the code. there should have been contestant's guess in the while statement. I corrected and edited in my post. @Bartdude if you scan for another value inside the loop for contestant's guess it will not result in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop over the options and keep track of the "smallest" distance.

```
minDistance = 50000000;  // arbitrarily high
for num in numbers {
     if num > correctGuess
          continue;    // skip numbers higher than correctGuess
     newDistance  = correctGuess - num
     if newDistance < minDistance
             minDistance = newDistance
             winngingGuess = num
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to be the closes to the winning one.

```
const int SIZE = 6;
int inputs[SIZE] = {12,9,7,13,4,0};
const int winningNumber = 15;
int matchIndex = -1;
int matchDifference = INT_MAX;
for(int i = 1; i < SIZE; ++i){
 int difference = std::abs( winningNumber - inputs[i]); //find the difference, how far apart
 if(difference < matchDifference){ //if smaller difference, i.e closer to winning number
   matchIndex = i; //save new closer data info
   matchDifference = difference;
 }       
}

std::cout << "Closest winning number to " << winningNumber << " is : " << inputs[matchIndex]  << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need variables to keep track of the min difference to make comparison.

```
int guesses[6] = { 12, 9, 7, 13, 4, 0};
int target = 15, win = -1, minDiff = 1000, diff;

foreach number in guesses //go through each number in the array
{
    if (number == target) //if number matches, you're done
    {
        win = number;
        break;
    }
    else if (number < target) //only proceed checking if number is less than target
    {
        diff = target - number;
        if (diff < minDiff) //if found a closer winner
        {
            minDiff = diff; //update the min difference
            win = number; //set the winner to the current number
        }
    }
}
```